# Round off floating point number to two decimal places in CLIPS

Tags: clips

CLIPS gives a floating point number upto many decimal places.

e.g

```
CLIPS> ( / 4 3)
1.33333333333333
```

How do I get a value rounded off to two decimal places (1.33 in this case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> (bind ?n (/ 4 3))
1.33333333333333
CLIPS> (/ (integer (* ?n 100)) 100)
1.33
CLIPS> 
(deffunction precision (?num ?digits)
  (bind ?m (integer (** 10 ?digits)))
  (/ (integer (* ?num ?m)) ?m))
CLIPS> (precision ?n 2)
1.33
CLIPS> (precision ?n 4)
1.3333
CLIPS> (precision ?n 0)
1.0
CLIPS>
```